# Filling nulls based on being categorical or numerical

Tags: python, python-3.x, null, fillna

Fill in the missing data with the mean values of the non-missing data in that column, for the numerical variables. If the variable is categorical, forward fill

Is there a way to have the code see the data type then fill the nulls depending on if it is a numerical variable or a categorical variable?

Comment: if you're reading the data as string, you can use the built-in `isnumeruc` function. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric)